# Resttemplate not working if there is bad request

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to send bad request from spring boot rest for validation error. Below is my method

```
public ResponseEntity<?>  getMyData(@Valid @ModelAttribute InputParms ipParms,BindingResult bindingResult )   {  

    MyObject obj=new MyObject ();

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(400).body(obj);
    }

    //my other code

}
```

On client side I have something like below. But it is throwing exception and code is not even reaching if block.

```
ResponseEntity<MyObject > resultResp=restTemplate.postForEntity(url,inputParam, MyObject .class);        
if(resultResp.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
    //my success code
}else {
    //my bad response code 
}
```

In the same code if i send status 200, it is working. What is I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default RestTemplate will throw an exception on a 4xx error. Instead of checking for the status code in the ResponseEntity, wrap the call in a subclass of [`RestClientException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientException.html), for example:

```
try {
    ResponseEntity<MyObject> resultResp = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,inputParam, MyObject .class);        
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    System.out.println("Error from server: " + e.getStatusCode() + " - " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

You could even catch `HttpClientErrorException` or `HttpServerErrorException` separately and handle errors differently for a 4xx and a 5xx error.